# Countif > 0 in Power Query (Excel)

Tags: excel, powerquery, countif

I have some stock price data with its % change and Day of the week calculated.

I have edited a query to get me the avg move for each day of the week (Represented by numbers).

[image]

in the next step I also want to calculate the no. of times the change in stock price is above 0 and below 0 for each of the days of the week.

I have created a table to see all records for each day

[image]

I would now like to calculate the no of times the 'chg' in above table is > 0 and no of times the 'chg' is < 0 for each of the days of the week.

I tried adding a custom column (DaysPositive) =Table.SelectRows([AllRecords], each([chg] > "0"))

but I get the foll error

[image]

would appreciate any help here to get me the 4 essential data points

Day of Week | Avg | No of Up Days | No of Down Days

thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Ticker", type text}, {"Day of week", Int64.Type}, {"% avg", type number}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Ticker", "Day of week"}, {
    {"belowzero", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [#"% avg"] < 0)), type number },
    {"abovezero", each Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(_, each [#"% avg"] > 0)), type number }
    })
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

[image]